# In terraform, how can I get the result of a data resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

terraform v0.12.17. I've read [Data Source: aws_ebs_snapshot](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ebs_snapshot.html) but it doesn't show me how I can use the results.

Say I want to create an AWS volume from the latest AWS snapshot. How can I use the data{} resource to get the latest snapshot and then use it to create a volume?

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_ebs_snapshot_ids" "jenkins_master" {    
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["jenkins-master"]
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "jenkins_master_ebs" {
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  size              = ??? // taken from result of above data{}
  snapshot_id       = ??? // taken from result of above data{}

  tags = {
    Name = "jenkins-master-ebs"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to Terraform documentation, you'll get a list of [`ids`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ebs_snapshot_ids.html#attributes-reference), so you can use something like this:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "jenkins_master_ebs" {
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  size              = 50 # Your custom size
  snapshot_id       = data.aws_ebs_snapshot_ids.jenkins_master.ids.0 # First element

  tags = {
    Name = "jenkins-master-ebs"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, though note that `[0]` is the more typical syntax for accessing the first index, as in `data.aws_ebs_snapshot_ids.jenkins_master.ids[0]`. The `.0` form is a legacy syntax only supported for backward compatibility with older Terraform versions.